# preferential multinomial model (with memory)

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, multinomial-distribution

I am modeling a system that is like having a container of an infinite number of colored balls. On each day $t$, I pull out a new set of $n_t$ balls and I count the number of balls that are red, green, blue, etc. For what its worth, $n_t$ is *at least* $\mathcal{O}(10^3)$ every day and there are roughly $\mathcal{O}(10^4)$ different colors of balls that are in my set of observations. The challenge is that I want to detect when a particular color $c$ has an "abnormal" fraction $f_{ct}$ of balls on day $t$.

My current approach is to treat this system as a multinomial process where, each day, you sample $n_t$ balls from the same container of infinite balls. Based on your observations to date, you can estimate the fraction of balls in the infinite container $\hat{f}_{ct}$ and use that to determine whether the observed fraction $f_{ct}$ is consistent with what you would expect from a multinomial distribution to see if $f_{ct}$ is significant. After observing this system for over 100 days, it is becoming clear that **the multinomial model is always detecting abnormal events**—which is obviously wrong—for two different reasons that I'm aware of.

First, the multinomial model does a pretty miserable job of capturing the fluctuations in $f_{ct}$. It is as if the container that is supplying the balls is aware of how many red balls it has already passed out and it preferentially gives out *more* red balls. Here is the cumulative distribution of the fraction of red balls compared with the cumulative distribution of the fraction of red balls that you might expect with a multinomial model with the same sequence of $n_t$'s:

[image: multinomial model does not match empirical distribution]

A second order effect is that $f_{ct}$ tends to be correlated from one day to the next. It is as if the container (which must be a very special "container" at this point) also has a memory that uses the number of red balls from the day before to preferentially bias the number of red balls that appear today. This is a bit more difficult to visualize, but here is the $f_{ct}$ for an arbitrary color $c$ compared to the quartiles of the corresponding multinomial timeseries with the same sequence of $n_t$'s:

[image: multinomial model does not have sufficient memory]

As you can see, when the empirical values are in top 25% percentile, they tend to stay there and when the values are in the bottom 25% percentile, they tend to stay there, too.

**Does anyone have any good suggestions for models that might be useful for capturing the large fluctuations in $f_{ct}$?** Quadruple bonus points will be awarded for those that have solutions that also address the "memory" of the very very special container, but I'd frankly be happy with doing a better job of modeling $P(f_{ct})$

> For the interested reader, the "colors" on the balls are [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) and the set of users on a particular website (like a forum) are writing content for the site and playing the role of the "container". The "preferential" and "memory" behaviors occur because people discussing a particular topic (*e.g.*, healthcare) tend to use the same words (*e.g.* "Obamacare") in rapid succession, leading to large spikes in the number of times these n-grams occur.

Comment: Maybe you could try sampling from a more limited set of "balls" each day: something like the set of balls seen in the last week. That should introduce some memory --- if there are more people who talking about obamacare one week it will be more likely to get sampled --- and also increase the variance of the distribution. (It doesn't seem *way* off as is, just eyeballing the 50% confidence interval).